# Apache Artemis listMessages MBean operation always returns nothing

Tags: jmx, activemq-artemis

I discovered MBeans recently and just checked out the ActiveMQ Artemis MBeans. Inside the queue attributes we see that there are some messages since the `MessageCount` is > 0.

[image]

But when I call the listMessages/AsJSON method the returned `String` is always empty:

[image]

Is there maybe I config I have missed? Other operations like `listMessageCounter` are working fine.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the messages are "in delivery" which means that they will not be returned by the `listMessages` or `listMessagesAsJSON` methods. Notice that `DeliveringCount` is `16` (i.e. the same as `Message Count`). Messages which are in delivery are those messages which have been dispatched from the broker to a client but the client has not yet acknowledged.

Try using `listDeliveringMessages` or `listDeliveringMessagesAsJSON` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much,
just a short follow-up question:
is there a way to view the payload of the message?

Comment: I recommend you create a new question since this isn't directly related to clarifying the existing answer. Asking new questions in comments is generally discouraged.